# Como remover o primeiro elemento de um list no python?

Tags: array, python, lista

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

Na linha de comando

```
> teste.py primeiro segundo
```

No script `teste.py`:

```
import sys

print(sys.argv)
```

E tenho o seguinte retorno:

```
['c:\\teste.py', 'primeiro', 'segundo']
```

Mas eu gostaria de remover o primeiro elemento. 
Quais são as possíveis maneiras de remover o primeiro de um `list` no `Python`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pode-se utilizar também o método [`del`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) para remover um item especificando o seu índice.

```
lista = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
del lista[0]

print lista # ['bar', 'baz']
```

A diferença entre `pop` e `del` é que `pop` retorna o valor removido, enquanto `del` só remove.

Veja um exemplo:

```
lista1 = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
lista2 = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd']

del lista1[0]
deleted = lista2.pop(0)

print (lista1) # ['bar', 'baz']
print (lista2) # ['bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd'] 
print ("O valor %s foi deletado da lista1" % deleted) # O valor aaa foi deletado da lista1
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://repl.it/9zs)</kbd>

Há também o método `remove()` que, ao invés de especificar o índice, é usado o valor para retirá-lo da lista.

```
lista = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
lista.remove('foo')

print lista # ['bar', 'baz']
```

O método `remove` vai remover o primeiro valor correspondente, supondo que na lista tenha dois valores iguais, somente o primeiro será removido.

Answer (score 5):

Utilize o método `pop`, documentação [aqui](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
lista = sys.argv
lista.pop(0)
```

Comment: No caso, `lista` passa a ter o primeiro elemento removido e `lista.pop(0)` retorna o elemento que foi removido?

Comment: Isso, se utilizar apenas `lista.pop()` remove e retorna o ultimo item da lista. @WallaceMaxters

Answer (score 3):

Uma outra forma seria pegar os itens a partir do segundo item da lista:

```
>>> a = [a, b, c, d, e, f]
>>> a = a[1:]
[b, c, d, e, f]
```

Comment: bacana! fiz o teste aqui. A única diferença é que ele não remove literalmente, mas ele apenas retorna sem o primeiro elemento